# Update Yup schema based on user input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I'm trying to write a schema where when the user selects an item from a dropdown, it checks whether the clicked item has an associated book or not. If it doesn't, the schema renders a message to the user.

```
ItemID:
    Yup.string()
        .required("Item is required")
        .when("ItemID", (itemID: string, passSchema: any) => {
            const selectedItem = this.props.AllItems.find((i) => i.ID === itemID);

            // Check if selected item includes a book
            if (selectedItem.Book) {
                // schema pass
            } else {
                // render message "This item does not include a book."
            }
        }),
```

I've done the above but its throwing this error: `Error: Cyclic dependency`. I'm assuming its trying to validate the same field that's changing. How can I get around this?